# Missing calendar events and can't create new ones

Tags: iphone, calendar

All of my past and future events have disappeared from my Calendar, the only events left in there are birthdays and Facebook events. All manually entered appointments etc., are gone.

Also, I cannot add new events anymore: the + sign is grayed out.

I just noticed this yesterday afternoon when I tried to add an event. I'm almost positive that they were there prior to that! How do I get my events back, and fix it so I can add events again!?

Comment: Do you sync with iCloud?  If so, are the events shown in the web interface?  If so, try turning off Calendar sync in Settings and then turning it back on.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Settings and click iCloud and turn on Calendars.

If that doesn't work, while in your Calendar, look at the bottom - "Today," "Calendar," and "Inbox." Click on Calendars. Somehow my "Home" calendar (which is where I save most entries, as opposed to "Calendar" or "Work") was unchecked. I couldn't see any old or future entries, and when I added entries and hit save, the day would be empty. When I re-checked "Home," everything reappeared.

It just wasn't showing "Home" entries. I hope your problem is this simple because I know how you feel like you're losing your mind when something like that happens!

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that your device is running the latest version of iOS. Sometimes when you are a couple of versions behind it can cause the phone to malfunction or do something that it has never done before. If you are updated and your phone is giving you issues then back up and restore your phone using iTunes to smooth out any bugs or errors in the device.